# Are questions about configuring an Operating System to work better specifically with Emacs on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

Specifically, this question: [Keycode for Shift + Return on OS X iterm2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26699/keycode-for-shift-return-on-os-x-iterm2)

The user wants to configure OSX (which would normally be off-topic), but that configuration is *specifically* for Emacs. In this example, it's about how OSX treats M-S-RET vs M-RET.

Are we better off migrating the question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2):

I think these questions are on topic, because they apply specifically to Emacs, and in many cases they require configuration of both the operating system and Emacs (for instance in the question you've linked to). If the question had nothing to do with Emacs (say, something like the alt key popping up a search menu in Unity when pressed and released without any other key pressed in between) then it would deserve to be moved.